# Why does a circle project its shadow as an upside down heart shape onto a corner instead of as an ellipse?

Tags: plane-geometry, projection

I was walking by a street corner and saw the attached image of a disc and its shadow. I was somewhat surprised to see an upside down heart shape instead of an ellipse projected onto the wall corner as the disc's shadow. [disc shadow projected onto 2 planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3bwX.jpg)
How can one predict if a shadow of a disc onto two planes will be primarily convex or include concave elements?

Comment: It is projecting an ellipse onto each of the walls behind it.  I'm not sure it makes a lot of sense to describe the shadow as concave since it is your perspective that is interpreting the shape as a two dimensional object.

Comment: This image is heart-breaking.

Comment: The light is hitting the disc with a given angle and the walls also form a certain (close to right) angle. It is  natural that you have a more or less symmetric shape divided into the two walls, and the angle of the light makes the shape that you see on each side.

Comment: Thanks for the laugh, Jean Marie. Matthew, likewise thanks; I hadn't realized the shadow form is also dependent on my location, so if I were a fly under the mirror, I might see the shadow as less of a heart shape; food for thought.

Comment: Thanks Javi. I guess it's almost like the circle was folded over a corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the sun sees of the disk is an ellipse. Hence, the shadowed area is the intersection of an elliptic cylinder with a dihedron. The two half-planes intersect the cylindre along two different ellipses, which meet at the common edge.

Comment: Thank you; the cylinder aspect is very helpful for visualization.

Answer (score 3):

There are two walls with  some $ 20^{\circ}$ turn about a common discontinuous vertical edge AD.

The shadow of ellipse major axis makes different angles to the vertical due to inclination of sun's rays.

It should be noted that the wall edge, vertical diameter of disc and the sun are in the same plane.

From the boundary of two semicircles in the projection we have two different tilted ellipse intersections as shadows cast through B and E on either wall around the discontinuity edge.

You can choose coloring  to get an upright heart too :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you; conceiving of the disc as two semi-circles is helpful.

Comment: ok,you can even replicate the projection in study room by a disc onto a cuboid box edge using bright lamp behind the disc to cast such a shadow.

Comment: Thank you. I might try that to compare the shadows cast from different positions.